# Only the first digit of my integer value is displayed in Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having a problem about getting the exact value of my integer in my database, because when i get it's value only the first digit of it's integer is displayed in php. For example the integer value in my database is "11" only "1" is displayed in my php. Here's my query.

```
$count=0;
$query="SELECT id from register";
$result = mysql_query($query);
('error in query:$query. ' .mysql_error());

  if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      extract($row);
$id[$count]=$id;
$count++;
}
}
 for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
echo"".$id[$count];
}
```

Comment: Please post all your code - the extract method is missing. Also, where does `$id` come from?

Comment: Because you are using `$id[$count]`, which means `get me the first number in this string at position $count` which is zero, in your case from `11` it gets `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $count=0;
$id = array();
$query="SELECT id from register";
$result = mysql_query($query);
('error in query:$query. ' .mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        extract($row);
        $id[$count]=$row['id'];
        $count++;
    }
}
for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
    echo "".$id[$count];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$count=0;
$query="SELECT id from register";
$result = mysql_query($query);
('error in query:$query. ' .mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id[$count++] = $row['id'];
    }
}

for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++) {
    echo $id[$count];
}
```

Comment: You still doing it wrong. He will get for the first record `1`, and for the rest `Uninitialized string offset: ...`

Comment: @machineaddict, why so!! `$row['id']` should return the whole exact id from DB. Isn't it?

Comment: Suppose there is one record in DB for register table i.e. 23. In the while loop, we are storing $id[0] = 23; and in down, if OP wants to loop it again, then it should print as $id[0] i.e. 23.

Comment: Yes, `$row['id']` is correct, `$id[$count++]` is wrong.

Comment: but the $id[$count++] . i didn't copy it. i just remove the extract($row)

Comment: @machineaddict, run the code once and then check, whether it is working correctly or not. I don't understand why this one is wrong `$id[$count++]` .. Please explain.

Comment: @prava: now I see you removed `extract($row);`. my bad... +1.

Comment: @machineaddict, no issues :) .. thank you for +1. Marky, glad that it worked.